# z-index for button over jquery slider

Tags: jquery, css, button, slider, z-index

I have a **full screen jquery slider** and I need to put **two buttons on it** (to increase and decrease the speed of the slider). I tried with z-index in the css file but it's not working.

```
div#lyr1 {
     position:relative;
    z-index:1;
    }
.ui.button {
  ...
  position:relative;
  z-index:2;}
```

And here's the html code

```
<div id="wn">
   <div id="lyr1">
      <div id="inner1"> 
          <img src="images/1-2.png" width="2000"height="1100" alt="" />
          <img id="rpt1" src="images/1-2.png" width="2000" height="1100" alt="" />
      </div> 
     <div class="ui button">Follow</div>
   </div>
</div>
```

How can I do it ?

Thank you.

Comment: Did you set `position:relative`? Both will need to be set to this, or else the z-index will not work.

Comment: @barry I edited the question and added the css code as well. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way the code is written, the `z-index` properties aren't really doing anything.  Since `ui button` is a child of `lyr1`, they don't share the same stacking context.

You'll need to move `ui button` to be a sibling of `lyr1`, and then you should see some results.

Like so:

```
<div id="wn">
   <div id="lyr1">
      <div id="inner1"> 
          <img src="images/1-2.png" width="2000"height="1100" alt="" />
          <img id="rpt1" src="images/1-2.png" width="2000" height="1100" alt="" />
      </div> 
   </div>
   <div class="ui button">Follow</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I understood what you mean but I don't see where's the change in the code you posted. Yet I put the button div outside the lyr1 div and now it's working so thank you !

Comment: @user2425899 – Yup, bone-headed.  Copied the code and then forgot to edit.  Changed it now.  In my defense they just delivered breakfast at work. :)

Comment: Haha that seems more than reasonable :) Now that I checked further I'm having an issue with the overflow. It was set to hidden but now it's not working anymore. any idea ?@barry

Comment: @user2425899 – Not without more info.  Might want to ask a new question.

Answer (score 0):

When I tested your original code, the button was on top of lyr1 without extra css. There must be something else in the slider that is effecting the layer stack.

```
<html>
<body>
<style>
div#lyr1 {
  background:#000;
}
.ui.button {
  background:#111;
  color:#ccc;
}
</style>
<div id="wn">
   <div id="lyr1">
      <div id="inner1"> 
          <img src="images/1-2.png" width="200"height="200" alt="" />
          <img id="rpt1" src="images/1-2.png" width="200" height="200" alt="" />
      </div> 
      <div class="ui button">Follow</div>
   </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you for your help :) the error was in the nesting and now that i changed it it's working good.

Comment: I thought about saying that right away, but when I tested your original code, it worked when nested. There must be something else impacting it in the slider.

Comment: Strange because when I adjusted the nesting it worked the way I wanted it